# Desktop environment for a touchscreen 2-in-1 laptop for an Ubuntu system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, desktop-environment, touchscreen

What are desktop environments, which runs on Ubuntu, with good 2-in-1 touchscreen laptop support?

Notable features:

- Touch-friendly buttons
- Cursor disappears when using touch input but shows where it was pressed
- Screen rotates based on accelerator
- Keyboard and touch pad automatically disabled based on how far back screen is folded

[image: touchscreen 2-in-1 laptop]

Comment: «the best desktop environment» This is absolutely opinion-based.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto how would you propose restating the question? One may ask simply for desktop environments for these laptops, but then every DE would work - regardless of they worked well for touchscreens or not.

Comment: See [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), especially the section about not being subjective. I would suggest you drop the "best DE" part and replace it with something like "a DE with good touch screen support". IMHO that would be a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about what you mean with *«based on Ubuntu»*. A desktop environment either runs on Ubuntu or it doesn't. Also, *«the best desktop environment»* is clearly a matter of opinion, therefore I will focus only on your bullet points.

> - Touch-friendly buttons
> - Cursor disappears when using touch input but shows where it was pressed

Ubuntu already ships with such a desktop environment, in fact it is the default one: [Unity](https://unity.ubuntu.com/). It was designed especially for working with both traditional and touch screen devices. As a matter of fact, the first Ubuntu tablets being sold currently make use of Unity for their interface.

> - Screen rotates based on accelerator

This is slightly unrelated to the DE. Screen rotation is related to the graphical server. Scripts automating this exist for different models (e.g. see [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/39l6yw/getting_screen_rotation_to_work/) for Microsoft Surface) but they are not universal. Your device might or might no be supported out of the box.

> - Keyboard and touch pad automatically disabled based on how far back screen is folded

This would also depend on the level of hardware support for your specific device.

Comment: You're right. Which runs on ubuntu.